# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^i = \theta (2^n )$

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to prove this I used the integration bounds

$\int_{0}^n 2^x dx <= \sum_{i=1}^n 2^i <=  \int_{1}^{n+1} 2^x dx$

$\frac{2^n}{ln(2)}-\frac{1}{ln2} <= \sum_{i=1}^n 2^i <= \frac{2^{n+1}}{ln2}- \frac{2}{ln2} $

then I added $\frac{2}{ln2}$ to the right side as it won't violate the inequality then it would be $\frac {2^n * 2}{ln2}$ then there exists c where c>0 and $c * 2^n >= \sum_{i=1}^n 2^i$ therefore $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^i = O(2^n)$ I can't prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^i =\Omega(2^n)$ to complete the proof

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! It's good that you have made an attempt to show effort, but using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and being more specific about what you tried would certainly help people to understand, and answer your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^i\ge 2^n$.

Comment: I know that but I can't prove that $\frac{2^n -1 }{ln2} <= 2^n$ as dividing by $ln2$ is a multiplication by 1.4 so it might increase the number

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused, $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$ if and only if there exists $k>0$ and $n_0$ such that $f(n)\ge kg(n)$ for $n\ge n_0$, right?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly right

Comment: But then $n_0=1$ and $k=1$ isn't enough?